# How to prove the vector distribution property geometrically.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a set $V$ and a field $F$. Suppose $V$ and $F$ satisfy all required axioms and together they form a vector space.

Let the vector space of particular interest be the set of all geometric vectors over the field of real numbers. We want to verify this set together with this field forms a vector space by proving the property of vector distribution of two scalars: $(\alpha + \beta) \bf{u} = \alpha \bf{u} + \beta \bf{u}$.

To achieve this prove geometrically, we construct a vector $(\alpha + \beta) \bf{u}$ and note how we may decompose this vector into two vectors, $\bf{a}$ and $\bf{b}$ per our definition of vector addition, which is a geometric definition. We note that $\bf{a}$ and $\bf{b}$ are in the direction of $\bf{u}$ and hence $\bf{a}$ $=$ k$\bf{u}$ and $\bf{b}$ $=$ m$\bf{u}$, where $m$ and $k$ are real scalars. We currently have established that $(\alpha + \beta) \bf{u} = $k$\bf{u} + $m$\bf{u}$.

Our goal is to prove that one appropriate choice of $m$ and $k$ is $m=\alpha$ and $k = \beta$. I can see how there are infinitely many choices of $m$ and $k$ and that some proportionality must be satisfied but I cannot quite find it.

Comment: I think if I were you, I would start with constructing $\alpha u + \beta u$ and show it is the same length and points in the same direction as $(\alpha + \beta)u$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering scalar multiplication of matrices, which you are talking about is distributive and as multiplication is distributive with respect to addition of matrices i.e., (a+b)A = aA+bA where a, b are scalars and A is a vector, so, 
(α+β)u=ku+mu here, α+β can assume any value which is equal to k+m which gives same result.
For example consider 10i as a vector which is along X-axis, we can have any number of vectors and also many combinations of vectors like [3i, 7i], [11i, -i],....

Hope I answered your question